pixi.js imports don't work in the index.d.ts file
I'm creating a library using typescript and pixi.js.
when i build the library i create also all the *.d.ts files and i merge all those files in only one index.d.ts file using "dts-bundle". the result is this:
    // Generated by dts-bundle v0.7.3
    // Dependencies for this module:
    /// <reference path="../pixi.js" />

declare module LIB{

    import { Container } from "pixi.js";

    export class BaseContainer extends Container{
        constructor();
    }

}

inside the library i can use "pixi.js" and all his modules.
the problem occur when i include this index.d.ts file inside another project.
the project see perfectly "BaseContainer" and i can normally create an instance of this class but, when i try to call, for example, the "addChild" method, the compiler give me the error:
Property 'addChild' does not exist on type 'BaseContainer'.

am I doing something wrong?
Thx a lot.
i tried to change some "dts-bundle" configurations and i tried also to change some "tsconfig" props, but nothing change

Why are you using /// <reference? It's not portable.

i removed it but the compiler is giving me those 2 errors: "Import declarations in a namespace cannot reference a module" and "Cannot find module 'pixi.js' or its corresponding type declarations."
